# Sublime Text Tab Indentation Indenting Entire Paragraph?

Tags: sublimetext3

I've recently discovered Sublime Text and since I'm new to using text editors like this, I had a question about indentation. When I'm not using Sublime for code, I type up my writing with it before taking it to a word processor for further processing. I've been having a little bit of trouble with the indentation regarding paragraphs. When I tab a paragraph, it seems to tab the entire paragraph rather than just the first line. It looks like the first paragraph in this [picture](http://puu.sh/7klnd).

I've tried using the wrap paragraph function which seems to allow me to tab just the first line but when I paste it in Microsoft Word, [it retains its wrap setting](http://puu.sh/7klpx). Is there anyway that I can just indent just the first line without having to wrap it? Or am I approaching it all wrong?

Comment: It is indenting just one line.  You just happen to have word wrap turned on.  Note the line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For a global effect you can add this to Preferences > Settings-User:

```
"indent_subsequent_lines": false
```

Because I code too, I add it to Preferences > Settings-More > Syntax Specific-User.

To do this properly, open a .txt file (or your preferred file type) and it will open/create a settings file for the specific file type. Then paste in this and save:

```
{
    "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime is a code editor, not a word processor. Although you may use it to type any kind of (plain) text, it's focused on editing code.

Sublime indents lines in a way that makes sense for a programming language. If you're looking for a tool to write anything like a report or a novel, maybe you should consider another tool.